# Integral Representation of a Double Sum

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

Let us assume we know the value of $x$ and $y$. I'm trying to write the following double sum as an integral. I went through many pages and saw various methods but I'm completely lost with my problem.

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n!} \sum_{m = 1}^{n} \frac{\left( m - 1 \right)!}{\left( m + y \right)!}$$

Could anyone please give me a hint so I can go about solving it myself?

Comment: The second sum is independent of $x$, and the first sum should look pretty familiar

Comment: This is not so simple according to the command of Mathematica `Sum[x^n/n!*(m - 1)!/(m + y)!, {n, 1, Infinity}, {m, 1, 
   n}] // FullSimplify` which results in $$\frac{x^{-y} \left(\left(e^x (y+1)-x-y-1\right) x^y+e^x (\Gamma (y+2,x)-\Gamma (y+2))\right)}{y \Gamma (y+2)} .$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hints:** Recall
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}^{-1}=(n+1)\int_{0}^1z^k(1-z)^{n-k}\,dz\tag{1.1}
\end{align*}
and consider
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\left( m - 1 \right)!}{\left( m + y \right)!}=\frac{1}{(y+1)!}\binom{m+y}{m-1}^{-1}\tag{1.2}
\end{align*}
We also need
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=1}^nz^{m-1}=\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x-1\tag{1.3}
\end{align*}

**Added [2021-10-26]:** Here is according to a comment from OP a rather detailed derivation which uses (1.1) to (1.3). It's admittedly not the shortest derivation, but here it is:

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty}&\color{blue}{\frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{(m-1)!}{(m+y)!}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(y+1)!}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{m=1}^n\binom{m+y}{m-1}^{-1}\tag{2.1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(y+1)!}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{m=1}^n(m+y+1)\int_{0}^1z^{m-1}(1-z)^{y+1}\,dz\tag{2.2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(y+1)!}\int_{0}^1(1-z)^{y+1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{m=1}^n(m+y+1)z^{m-1}\,dz\tag{2.3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(y+1)!}\int_{0}^1(1-z)^{y+1}\\
> &\qquad\cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}
> \left(\frac{1-z^n}{(1-z)^2}-\frac{nz^n}{1-z}+(y+1)\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}\right)\,dz\tag{2.4}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(y+1)!}\int_{0}^1(1-z)^{y+1}\\
> &\qquad\cdot\left(\frac{e^x-e^{xz}}{(1-z)^2}-\frac{xze^{xz}}{1-z}+(y+1)\frac{e^x-e^{xz}}{1-z}\right)\,dz\tag{2.5}\\
> &=\frac{e^x}{(y+1)!}\int_{0}^1(1-z)^{y-1}\left(1-e^{x(z-1)}\right)\,dz\\
> &\qquad-\frac{xe^x}{(y+1)!}\int_{0}^1(1-z)^{y}ze^{x(z-1)}\,dz\\
> &\qquad+\frac{e^x}{y!}\int_{0}^1(1-z)^{y}\left(1-e^{x(z-1)}\right)\,dz\tag{2.6}\\
> &=\frac{e^x}{\Gamma(y+2)}\left(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{\Gamma(y)-\Gamma(y,x)}{x^y}\right)\\
> &\qquad+\frac{xe^x}{\Gamma(y+2)}\left(\frac{\Gamma(y+2)-\Gamma(y+2,x)}{x^{y+2}}\right)\\
> &\qquad-\frac{xe^x}{\Gamma(y+2)}\left(\frac{\Gamma(y+1)-\Gamma(y+1,x)}{x^{y+1}}\right)\\
> &\qquad+\frac{e^x}{\Gamma(y+1)}\left(\frac{1}{y+1}-\frac{\Gamma(y+1)-\Gamma(y+1,x)}{x^{y+1}}\right)\tag{2.7}\\
> &=\frac{e^x}{y\Gamma(y+1)}-\frac{e^x}{yx^y}-\frac{1}{y\Gamma(y+1)}+\frac{e^x\Gamma(y+1,x)}{yx^y\Gamma(y+1)}\tag{2.8}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{e^x-1}{y\Gamma(y+1)}+\frac{e^x}{yx^y}\left(\frac{\Gamma(y+1,x)}{\Gamma(y+1)}-1\right)}\tag{2.9}
> \end{align*}

**Cross-check:**

We perform a cross-check with the Mathematica generated result stated in the comment section above by @user64494.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{\frac{x^{-y}\left(\left(e^x(y+1)-x-y-1\right)x^y+e^x\left(\Gamma(y+2,x)-\Gamma(y+2)\right)\right)}{y\Gamma(y+2)}}\\
> &\qquad=\frac{e^x(y+1)-x-y-1}{y\Gamma(y+2)}+\frac{e^x}{yx^y}\left(\frac{\Gamma(y+2,x)}{\Gamma(y+2)}-1\right)\\
> &\qquad=\frac{e^x(y+1)}{y\Gamma(y+2)}-\frac{x}{y\Gamma(y+2)}-\frac{y+1}{y\Gamma(y+2)}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\frac{e^x}{yx^y}\left(\frac{(y+1)\Gamma(y+1,x)+x^{y+1}e^{-x}}{\Gamma(y+2)}-1\right)\tag{3.1}\\
> &\qquad=\frac{e^x}{y\Gamma(y+1)}-\frac{x}{y\Gamma(y+2)}-\frac{1}{y\Gamma(y+1)}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\frac{e^x}{yx^y}\frac{\Gamma(y+1,x)}{\Gamma(y+1)}+\frac{x}{y\Gamma(y+2)}-\frac{e^x}{yx^y}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{=\frac{e^x-1}{y\Gamma(y+1)}+\frac{e^x}{yx^y}\left(\frac{\Gamma(y+1,x)}{\Gamma(y+1)}-1\right)}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with the derivation (2.9).

**Comment:**

- In (2.1) we use the binomial identity (1.2).
- In (2.2) we use the integral representation (1.1).
- In (2.3) we do some rearrangements.
- In (2.4) we apply the geometric series expansion addressed in (1.3) in the form
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{m=1}^nz^{m-1}=\frac{1-z^n}{(1-z)},
  \qquad \sum_{m=1}^nmz^{m-1}=\frac{1-z^n}{(1-z)^2}-\frac{nz^n}{1-z}\\
  \end{align*}
- In (2.5) we use the exponential series expansion addressed in (1.3).
- In (2.6) we separate the terms and factor out $e^x$.
- In (2.7) we evaluate the integrals (with some help of Wolfram Alpha) using the *[Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)* $\Gamma(y)$ and the *[Incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)* $\Gamma(y,x)$.
- In (2.8) we collect terms and simplify using the recurrence relations
  \begin{align*}
  \Gamma(y+1)=y\Gamma(y), \qquad \Gamma(y+1,x)=y\Gamma(y,x)+\frac{x^y}{e^x}
  \end{align*}
- In (2.9) we make a final simplification.
- In (3.1) we use again the recurrence relation given in (2.8).

Comment: So I'm familiar with formulations 2, 3 and 4 but could you please tell me more about the first formulation for more reading? It looks like we're integrating a part of the binomial pmf but I don't see why.

Comment: @CactusHamster: Here we use an integral representation of the beta function. I've added a reference.

Comment: Thank you. I understood the procedure in other answers but I'm not sure how we can simplify the sum using formulations you mentioned. Could you please help me?

Comment: @CactusHamster: I've added a rather detailed derivation. :-)

Comment: Thank you, now I see it and it matches the comments of two other users.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$
\begin{array}{l}
 S(x,y) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{x^n }}{{n!}}\sum\limits_{m = 1}^n {\frac{{\left( {m - 1} \right)!}}{{\left( {m + y} \right)!}}} }  =  \\ 
  = \sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\left( {m - 1} \right)!}}{{\left( {m + y} \right)!}}\sum\limits_{n = m + 1}^\infty  {\frac{{x^n }}{{n!}}} }  =  \\ 
  = \sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\left( {m - 1} \right)!}}{{\left( {m + y} \right)!}}\left( {e^x  - \sum\limits_{n = 0}^m {\frac{{x^n }}{{n!}}} } \right)}  =  \\ 
  = e^x \sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\left( {m - 1} \right)!}}{{\left( {m + y} \right)!}}\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{e^x }}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^m {\frac{{x^n }}{{n!}}} } \right)}  =  \\ 
  = e^x \sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\left( {m - 1} \right)!}}{{\left( {m + y} \right)!}}\left( {1 - \frac{{\Gamma \left( {m + 1,x} \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( {m + 1} \right)}}} \right)}  =  \\ 
  = e^x \sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\Gamma \left( m \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( {m + 1 + y} \right)}}\frac{{\gamma \left( {m + 1,x} \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( {m + 1} \right)}}}  =  \\ 
  =  \cdots  \\ 
 \end{array}
$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate why $\frac{1}{e^x} \sum_{n=0}^{m} \frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{\Gamma(m+1,x)}{\Gamma(m+1)}$?

Comment: @cactushamster: that's a well known identity for the Regularized Incomplete Gamma function that you can find in most sources about it

Answer (score 0):

$$ \sum_{m = 1}^{n} \frac{\left( m - 1 \right)!}{\left( m + y \right)!}=\frac{1}{y^2\, \Gamma (y)}-\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{y\, \Gamma (n+y+1)}$$
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n!} \sum_{m = 1}^{n} \frac{\left( m - 1 \right)!}{\left( m + y \right)!}=\frac{e^x-1}{y^2 \Gamma (y)}-\frac 1 y\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{(n+y)!}$$
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{(n+y)!}=\frac 1 {x^y}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{(n+y)}}{(n+y)!}=\frac {e^x} {x^y}\frac{ (y+1) (\Gamma (y+1)-\Gamma (y+1,x))}{\Gamma (y+2)}$$
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{(n+y)!}=\frac {e^x} {x^y}\Bigg[1-\frac{\Gamma (y+1,x)}{\Gamma (y+1)} \Bigg]=\frac {e^x} {x^y}\Bigg[1-\frac {x^{1+y}}{y!}E_{-y}(x)\Bigg]$$ Recombining all the above
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n!} \sum_{m = 1}^{n} \frac{\left( m - 1 \right)!}{\left( m + y \right)!}=-\frac{e^x x^{-y}}{y}+\frac{e^x (x E_{-y}(x)+1)-1}{y^2 \Gamma (y)}$$

Comment: Thank you. I'm very new to this areas so could you tell me more about $\frac{\Gamma (y+1,x)}{\Gamma (y+1)}=\frac {x^{1+y}}{y!}E_{-y}(x)$?

Comment: @CactusHamster : It is the relation between the incomplete gamma function and the exponential integral function. By the way, nice username

Comment: Thank you, I understood every part but the first equality. Could you please give me a hint on how to show it holds?

Comment: Ok just got it. We used identity $\Gamma(a+1) = a \cdot \Gamma(a)$ recursively.

Comment: @CactusHamster. You got it ! I did not see your question on time (meetings)